# Mobile Create Sales Quote from Opportunity

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create a customization to add the ability to create a sales quote from the opportunity screen on Acumatica mobile. Below is my mobile screen update for CR304000 (Opportunities). It adds a tab for Quotes and add icon for creating the quote.

Currently when I click the add icon it open a "Quotes" screen (first image) but when it is saved the app throws an error(second image).

I believe most of my issue is that it doesn't pull up the same screen as if the quote was being created via the sales quote screen(third image).

```
  update container "OpportunitySummary" {
    add layout "QuotesTab" {
      displayName = "Quotes"
      layout = "DataTab"
      add containerLink "Quotes"
    }
  }
  update container "Quotes" {
    fieldsToShow = 4
    listActionsToExpand = 1
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 1
    add field "Date"
    add field "Type"
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add recordAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
      after = Close
    }
    add selectionAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
}
```

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZjMj.jpg)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmoMK.jpg)

[third image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDFUg.jpg)

Comment: I don't use Opportunities, but the rule of thumb is that the mobile app must mirror the screen in ERP.  If you cannot add a quote to that container directly, you would need to look at the action that is used to create it and call that action.  If it takes you to a different screen, you would need to make sure the parts of that screen that you need are also setup in the mobile app.  I think you are on the right track with questioning which screen is popping up.